# Node JS - Socket.io-client Not Working Well

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This code works perfectly by running in the browser. However I'm trying to make it work on Node JS without success.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var url = 'wss://*********.com/';
    var socket = io(url, {
      transport: ['websocket']
    });

    console.log('iniciado');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('connected');
      socket.emit('checkout-load', {
        shopperSessionCode: "0971852c97c964e6c01ccfa7c1b131c01550675960125",
        checkoutMode: "10",
        locale: "pt_BR",
        timezone: "America/Sao_Paulo",
        cookie: "",
        forceShowBillet: 0,
        forceHideBillet: 0,
        forceHidePayPal: 0,
        forceHideTransfer: 0,
        forceHideTrial: 0,
        forceHideMultipleCards: 0,
        forceHideSamsungPay: 0,
        defaultInstallmentOption: 0,
        thumb: 0,
        checkoutCustomId: null,
        templateLayoutId: null,
        hotAffiliateCookiesInfo: {
          urlDomain: ".*****.com",
          hotAffiliateCookieVO: [{
            name: "hotd",
            value: "",
            domain: ".hotmart.com"
          }]
        },
        urlCheckout: "https://*******",
        previousUrl: "https://********",
        callbackEvent: "checkoutLoaded",
        affiliationReference: [{
          amount: 1,
          affiliationReference: "******"
        }]
      });
    });
    socket.on('checkoutLoaded', function(data) {
      console.log('evento recebido');
      console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('disconnect');
    });
    socket.on('ping', function() {
      console.log('ping');
    });
    socket.on('pong', function() {
      console.log('pong');
    });

    console.log('finalizado');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The code connects to the websocket, however the socket.emit ('...') command is not sent correctly after the connection. Also tested using socket.send () and also does not work.

Node JS code:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('wss://*******/',{transports: ['websocket']});

console.log('iniciado');

socket.on('connect', function(data){
    console.log('connected');

    socket.emit('checkout-load', {
        shopperSessionCode:"0971852c97c964e6c01ccfa7c1b131c01550675960125",
        checkoutMode:"10",
        locale:"pt_BR",
        timezone:"America/Sao_Paulo",
        cookie:'',
        forceShowBillet:0,
        forceHideBillet:0,
        forceHidePayPal:0,
        forceHideTransfer:0,
        forceHideTrial:0,
        forceHideMultipleCards:0,
        forceHideSamsungPay:0,
        defaultInstallmentOption:0,
        thumb:0,
        checkoutCustomId:null,
        templateLayoutId:null,
        hotAffiliateCookiesInfo:{
            urlDomain:".hotmart.com",
            hotAffiliateCookieVO:[
                {
                    name:"hotd",
                    value:"******",
                    domain:".hotmart.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        urlCheckout:"https://********",
        previousUrl:"https://************",
        callbackEvent:"checkoutLoaded",
        affiliationReference:[
            {
                amount:1,
                affiliationReference:"*****"
            }
        ]
    });
});

socket.on("checkoutLoaded", function(data){
    console.log('evento recebido: checkoutLoaded');
    console.log(data);
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222)

Answer (score 1):

Please check socket.io documentation.It is clearly mentioned that it is not websocket implemention.

https://socket.io/docs/#What-Socket-IO-is-not

Comment: Thank yo. Do you know of any other alternative for me to consume these services through Node JS?